# ASP.net MVC oData route with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, odata

Is it possible to use addresses like that :

http://community.innovacall.local/odata/contactcompetencies(id=GetById/4a50412c-4e36-468a-b7d1-a36a78f02b02)?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=10

I handmade a workaround for the second one but I'm sure there is a out of the box solution.

```
Guid userId = Guid.Parse(Request.Properties["MS_ODataPath"].ToString().Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0].Split('=')[1]);
```

Could you help me to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` to separate query string options

Use `$filter` to filter the data (see [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions/#45_Filter_System_Query_Option_filter)):

> community.innovacall.local/odata/contactcompetencies?$filter=id eq 1

Use `guid'<value>'` for guids (see [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem))

> community.innovacall.local/odata/contactcompetencies?$filter=id eq guid'4a50412c-4e36-468a-b7d1-a36a78f02b02'

Use `$inlinecount=allpages` to get a count of records (see [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions/#49_Inlinecount_System_Query_Option_inlinecount))

> community.innovacall.local/odata/contactcompetencies?$filter=id eq guid'4a50412c-4e36-468a-b7d1-a36a78f02b02'&$inlinecount=allpages

Use `$top` and `$skip` to page through the results (see [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions/#43_Top_System_Query_Option_top) and [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions/#44_Skip_System_Query_Option_skip))

> community.innovacall.local/odata/contactcompetencies?$filter=id eq guid'4a50412c-4e36-468a-b7d1-a36a78f02b02'&$inlinecount=allpages&$top=10&$skip=10